# awk script not working properly in SunOS (which worked well with Red Hat)

Tags: unix, awk, solaris, sunos

I was looking out for a file replacement functionality to be done in `awk`. I had a solution that worked well for Red Hat Linux flavour but it is not working well with SunOS 5.10.  It would be great if someone can help troubleshoot the issue.

**Source file** (src.txt)

```
aaaa
uid=xxxx
pwd=nnnn
u_no=12345
bbbb
uid=yyyy
pwd=eeee
zzzz
uid=yyyy
pwd=eeee
```

**Reference file** (ref.txt)

```
block,parameter,value
aaaa,uid,1a1a
aaaa,pwd,1b1b
bbbb,uid,2a2a
zzzz,pwd,9b9b
zzzz,uid,9a9a
bbbb,pwd,2b2b
```

**Required output file** (tgt.txt)

The target file should be an updated source file based on the lookup values from the reference file as follows:

```
aaaa
uid=1a1a
pwd=1b1b
u_no=12345
bbbb
uid=2a2a
pwd=2b2b
zzzz
uid=9a9a
pwd=9b9b
```

**Code**

```
awk -F= '
FNR==NR {
split($0,b,",")
a[b[1] FS b[2]]=b[3]
next} 
!/=/ {
f=$1
print
next} 
{
print $1"="(a[f FS $1]?a[f FS $1]:$2)}
' ref.txt src.txt > tgt.txt
```

The code solution was given by one of our friends here in Stack Overflow and it worked pretty well in Red Hat Linux.

When I tried to copy it to SunOS 5.10, it first showed a syntax error at:

```
!/=/ {
```

I replaced the field separator value and it stopped showing syntax error.

```
OFS="="
```

For this, the script executes, but just prints the source file values (not an updated value).

Can you help me find a solution for this?

Comment: You should be able to replace the `!/=/` with `$0 !~ /=/`.  Have you printed what the first section of the code is producing — the values in b[1], b[2], b[3]?  Have you printed the matched values in the last section ($1, $2)?

Comment: Note that Solaris 10 has `nawk` and `awk` which have lesser number of features than GNU Awk. You may try to use `gawk`, but it only available in external packages: i.e. http://www.opencsw.org/package/gawk/

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- Tried "....$0 !~ /=/...." .. Didnt work... The syntax error is gone... but functionality not working..... :-(

Comment: @myaut -- cant go for gawk buddy... Anyway.. my scipt was working fine  with red hat with just awk...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nawk` (new awk) or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` (POSIX awk) with Solaris. `awk` is the original legacy version.

Here is something that works:

```
nawk -F= '
FNR==NR {
split($0,b,",")
a[b[1] FS b[2]]=b[3]
next}
$0 !~ "=" {
f=$1
print
next}
{
print $1"="(a[f FS $1]?a[f FS $1]:$2)}
' ref.txt src.txt > tgt1.txt
```

Comment: did u edit your post ??? I thought the previous solution which you provided worked for me.....

Comment: Sorry I did edit indeed. I'm going to check on a real Solaris 10 instance. Will update later.

Comment: I just checked and it works fine on a Solaris 10 update 10 machine. The only change that might confuse you is the output is on `tgt1.txt`, not `tgt.txt` (I changed it to be able to compare GNU awk and Solaris awk outputs).